# Failed to load resource : Internal Server Error (500) : jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services

We are using jQuery 3.3.1 in our project. When we are using and testing on localhost the jQuery works fine and its loading without any issue.
However, now we have deployed our web application on AWS and after deploying it is giving the below error

> Failed to load resource : the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

We are loading third party payment providers iFrame in our html page. Is that causing an issue ? If it is an issue then why does it works fine in localhost ?

Also, we have kept the file in our solution itself and tried with jQuery CDN as well. But it gives the same error.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>PaymentProviders</title>
    <script src="~/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>Payment Provider Name:- </label>
        @Html.DropDownList("ID", new SelectList(ViewBag.PaymentProvidersList, "ID", "PaymentProviderName"), "Please select", new { @id = "ddlPaymentProviders", @onChange = "SelectedValue(this)" })
    </div>

    <div id="divContainer"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function SelectedValue(ddlObject) {

        var selectedText = ddlObject.options[ddlObject.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/Index",
            data: { 'paymentProviderName': selectedText },
            success: function (data) {

                $('#divContainer').html(data);
                $('#divContainer iframe').height("500");
                
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Below is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: 500 is an internal Server error, look into your Server logs for more informations

Comment: @Jens you mean I should look for the logs on AWS ? As we have deployed the application there only.

Comment: The error is in /Home/Index. What I would suggest in your browser's address bar goto that URL with the querystring /Home/Index?paymentProviderName= and the payment provider's name and see what error is returned.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing included in your question will really allow us to give you a definite answer as to the cause of your issue. A `500` error means that your backend code is erroring out, not your front-end. There should be error logs somehwere in AWS that would report the actual error you're throwing, or you may be able to look in the Developer Console _Network_ tab and review the _Response_.

Comment: For a temp test, you may consider enable `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in production. Or, enable `stdoutLogEnabled` log to check the server side error.

Comment: @TylerRoper May I know what other details I can provide? I will be glad to provide those. What i am asking is if refer the jquery on test html page it doesn't give any problem but on this page I am loading the iFrame. Secondly the error which I have given i got it from response only, which is shown in screenshot for which line i am getting the error in jquery file.

Comment: @imvain2 It is giving Http Error 500, currentyl unable to handle the request. Can you tell me what exactly is going wrong here ?

Comment: As this is a server side error NOT jquery side, I would suggest going into your server side code and commenting out lines until you stop seeing the error.